# How to check if predicate expression was changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, predicatebuilder, linqkit

```
 var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<o_order>();
```

This is my predicate expression, where on some certain conditions I will append expressions with it.

**Likewise**

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
                predicate = predicate.And(s => s.OrderID.ToString().Contains(param.sSearch));
```

Now my question is if this expression doesn't pass by this condition then would there be any expression? and how would I know if it returns no expression with it.

Simply I want to do-

`if(predicate==null)` or `if(predicate contains no expression)`

Comment: what is `PredicateBuilder`?

Comment: @dotctor, a LINQ expression builder ! No?

Comment: @dotctor: it's "traditional" class name for a utility operations on Linq predicates, see i.e. http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Please consider marking an answer that solved your problem as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so easy, you probably didn't consider that. Since PredicateBuilder builds **new predicate instances** each time (notice that you must write `predicate = predicate.And...` so you are replacing the pred each time), then you can simply just **remember the original** value and eventually compare the final value against that.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<o_order>();
var oldPredicate = predicate;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
    predicate = predicate.And(s => ........... );  // replace!

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(....))
    predicate = predicate.And(s => ........... );  // replace!

if(predicate == oldPredicate)   // was it changed?
    ; // no filters applied
else
    ; // some filters applied
```

It'd be hard however to tell **which** filters were applied. If you need to know that, then you must store the information alongside (or you have to analyze the predicate tree, which can be harder):

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<o_order>();
var oldPredicate = predicate;

bool case1applied = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(....);
if (case1applied)
    predicate = predicate.And(s => ........... );

bool case2applied = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(....);
if (case2applied)
    predicate = predicate.And(s => ........... );

if(predicate == oldPredicate) // or the hard way: !case1applied && !case2applied
    ; // no filters applied
else
    if(case1applied && case2applied) // all filters applied
    else ....
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the `IsStarted` property seems to show if a predicate has been assigned.

In my code I've used that to build up composite search statements where the search parameters are optional.  E.g.

```
var quoteDatePredicate= PredicateBuilder.New<SearchData>();

if (searchCriteria.QuoteFromDate.HasValue)
{
    quoteDatePredicate.And(x => x.QuoteDate >= searchCriteria.QuoteFromDate);
}

var saleDatePredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<SearchData>();

if (searchCriteria.SaleDate.HasValue)
{
    saleDatePredicate.And(x => x.SaleDate >= searchCriteria.SaleDateFrom);
}
```

And then I create another predicate variable and use an `If` statement to add any predicates that were actually assigned to:

```
var datesPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<SearchData>();

if (quoteDatePredicate.IsStarted) datesPredicate.Or(quoteDatePredicate);
if (saleDatePredicate.IsStarted) datesPredicate.Or(saleDatePredicate);
```

So far that seems to work fine in my code.

Alternatively, comparing an assigned and unassigned predicate variable in the debugger seems to suggest you could use this to check if a predicate has been assigned:

```
if (dueOutOfDatePredicate.Parameters[0].Name = "f")
```

I haven't tried that though.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, PredicateBuilder exposes no methods that return a list of the expressions used. You could however store the conditions used to add expressions to the PredicateBuilder

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<o_order>();
var cond1 = /* condition 1 */
var cond2 = /* condition 2 */
...
if (cond1) { /* add expression for condition 1 */ }
if (cond2) { /* add expression for condition 2 */ }
...
if (!cond1 && !cond2 && ...) { /* handle case of no expressions added */ }
```